# Stop diagonal lines to display after extracting powerclip contents

Tags: clip, coreldraw

There was one time when I have a project that need duplication of objects in CorelDraw in order to save time. That moment then, I accidentally powerclipped an object inside an object that is to be duplicated for future use of other objects that needs same dimensions as the object I'm working now. As a result I extracted its objects and what happened is that, yes the objects got extracted but the container object have had diagonal lines from its objects. What can I do to stop or rather not come up again with a situation like this?

[image: Consider situation like this (image)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1) Right click object, select Frame Type - None

2) Layout menu > enable Layout Toolbar. third button is remove frame

Unfortunately it is not possible to do such an operation on more than one object at the same time.